# PayPal to differents accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

i want to make a website where a seller can create his products and the buyer can pay directly to his paypal account. i know how to use the IPN notification for a lonely business account per website. Do i have to ask all my seller to configure my IPN Url in their paypal account? or is it enough to use this " $this->paypal->add_field('notify_url',www.site.com/ipn_paypal'));"?

I am just asking if there is another requirement for seller to make this type of sites. Does paypal allow this?